# Create specific resistances across a constant current source

Tags: microcontroller, resistors, constant-current

I'd like to emulate the controls on a garage door circuit programmatically. As far as I can tell the circuit acts like a constant current source and sends out 10mA to the wall console. I'd like the wall console to stay in place and be usable at the same time. Here's a simulation of it:

[image: Circuit]

[(On falstad)](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2050%205%2050%0Ai%20464%2064%20384%2064%200%200.01%0Az%20464%2096%20384%2096%202%20default-zener%0Aw%20384%2064%20384%2096%200%0Aw%20464%2064%20464%2096%200%0Aw%20384%20176%20384%2096%200%0Aw%20464%20176%20464%2096%200%0Ar%20384%20176%20384%20240%200%2082%0A162%20384%20304%20464%20304%202%20default-led%201%200%200%200.01%0Ar%20384%20240%20384%20304%200%20121%0Ax%20384%2035%20464%2038%204%2014%20Garage%5CsDoor%0Ab%20320%2016%20506%20112%200%0As%20384%20176%20464%20176%200%201%20false%0As%20384%20240%20464%20240%200%201%20false%0Aw%20464%20304%20464%20240%200%0Aw%20464%20240%20464%20176%200%0A368%20384%2064%20352%2080%200%200%0A)

I know I could do it by just replacing the switches with 3 relays, but I'm looking for something smaller/simpler. I'd rather use just one relay to my 'override circuit', but I can't figure out how to create the apparently load on the circuit. It seems anything I put in there results in too much of a voltage change on the original circuit (considered analogue switches, mosfet, bjt, digital pot).

[Here's a version of the circuit with relays](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+10.20027730826997+50+5+50%0Ai+464+64+384+64+0+0.01%0Az+464+96+384+96+2+default-zener%0Aw+384+64+384+96+0%0Aw+464+64+464+96+0%0Av+144+432+144+336+0+0+40+3.3+0+0+0.5%0Aw+384+144+384+96+0%0Aw+464+160+464+96+0%0As+144+192+192+192+0+1+false%0Ar+416+240+416+304+0+121%0As+144+272+192+272+0+1+false%0As+144+336+192+336+0+1+false%0Aw+464+160+464+240+0%0Aw+464+272+464+368+0%0Aw+144+272+144+192+0%0Ax+384+35+464+38+4+14+Garage%5CsDoor%0Ab+352+16+490+112+0%0Ax+132+161+223+164+4+14+Microcontroller%0Ab+113+127+229+476+0%0Ax+250+185+279+188+4+12+Open%0Ax+251+262+276+265+4+12+Lock%0Ax+243+313+275+316+4+12+Lights%0Ar+608+160+608+240+0+121%0A162+608+112+528+112+2+default-led+1+0+0+0.01%0Aw+528+112+528+160+0%0Ar+608+240+608+320+0+100%0Aw+528+368+528+320+0%0Aw+608+160+608+112+0%0Aw+528+240+528+160+0%0Aw+528+320+528+240+0%0Ax+554+336+583+339+4+12+Open%0Ax+552+259+577+262+4+12+Lock%0Ax+551+175+583+178+4+12+Lights%0Aw+608+320+608+432+0%0As+528+160+608+160+0+1+true%0As+528+320+608+320+0+1+true%0As+528+240+608+240+0+1+false%0Ab+512+64+643+355+0%0Ax+528+86+609+89+4+14+Wall%5CsConsole%0Ar+416+240+464+240+0+82.5%0Aw+192+192+336+192+0%0Aw+192+272+336+272+0%0Aw+144+336+144+272+0%0Aw+608+432+400+432+0%0Aw+464+368+528+368+0%0A178+384+144+384+192+1+1+0.2+0+0.05+1000000+0.02+20%0A178+384+224+384+272+1+1+0.2+0+0.05+1000000+0.02+20%0A178+384+288+384+336+1+1+0.2+0+0.05+1000000+0.02+20%0Aw+400+192+384+224+0%0Aw+400+272+384+288+0%0Aw+368+192+416+160+0%0Aw+416+160+464+160+0%0Aw+368+272+416+240+0%0Aw+368+336+416+304+0%0Aw+464+240+464+272+0%0Aw+400+336+400+432+0%0Aw+336+336+192+336+0%0Aw+352+192+352+272+0%0Aw+352+272+352+336+0%0Aw+352+336+352+432+0%0Aw+352+432+144+432+0%0A).
[image: Circuit with relays]

Would anyone be able to provide a suggestion on another way this could be done?

Edit: Switch to 3 relays.

Comment: Try FETs instead of relays. Much simpler to deal with.

Comment: These simulated relays do have an NC connection. The NC connection is the right one...

Comment: Why do you need to disconnect the console circuit when any of the other relays activate?

Comment: By the way, you don't need to use resistors with relay coils, if you're using the  right voltage.

Comment: Also, *if* it's easier, your circuit can be a constant-voltage sink (e.g. with a DAC controlling a transistor via an op-amp).

Comment: @Hearth I looked at mosfets, but then to disconnect the original circuit it seemed that Form C or Form B mosfets all had a higher resistance that seems like it would throw off the values.

Comment: @PeterHofmann If it says they're form C or form B, then you're not looking at MOSFETs but at MOSFET-based solid-state relays. Just get a basic power FET and drive it with an appropriate drive circuit (depending on requirements this can be anything from a direct connection to the microcontroller to a complicated dedicated circuit board)

Comment: @user253751 Good point - edited to to make things clearer. The relays are just examples, I'm really using signal ones and transistors to control. I'll read up on constant-voltage sinks and see if that makes sense.

Comment: @brhans I'm trying to provide a known resistance across the circuit. That seemed easier if I removed the other components. The original controls also take out the LED on a button press, for example. If I didn't it seems it would be more complicated (or I'm missing something).

Comment: I meant: if the current is always the same, you could make your circuit create a constant voltage instead of a constant resistance.

Comment: @user253751 I have no idea how to do that yet, but I like the idea.

Comment: @Hearth okay... so still the relay to the override circuit, but then 3 mosfets to decide the path through there? (and mosfets with a low Rds on?). Ie. not trying to use the relay as a variable resistor?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PN2222A NPN's as an approx 5 Ohm switch at this current level [simulated here.](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%200%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2050%205%2050%0Ai%20464%2064%20384%2064%200%200.01%0Az%20464%2096%20384%2096%202%20default-zener%0Aw%20384%2064%20384%2096%200%0Aw%20464%2064%20464%2096%200%0Aw%20384%20144%20384%2096%200%0Aw%20464%20144%20464%2096%200%0Ar%20384%20144%20384%20224%200%2082%0A162%20384%20320%20464%20320%202%20default-led%201%200%200%200.01%0Ar%20384%20224%20384%20320%200%20121%0Ax%20384%2035%20455%2038%204%2014%20Garage%5CsDoor%0Ab%20320%2016%20506%20112%200%0As%20384%20144%20464%20144%200%201%20true%0As%20384%20224%20464%20224%200%201%20true%0Aw%20464%20320%20464%20224%200%0Aw%20464%20224%20464%20144%200%0A368%20384%2064%20352%2080%200%200%0At%20432%20272%20432%20240%201%201%20-2.9943535900320533%209.999999999613377e-11%20100%0Aw%20416%20240%20384%20224%200%0Aw%20448%20240%20464%20224%200%0Ag%20464%20320%20464%20336%200%0Ar%20432%20272%20496%20272%200%201000%0Ar%20432%20192%20496%20192%200%201000%0Aw%20448%20160%20464%20144%200%0Aw%20416%20160%20384%20144%200%0At%20432%20192%20432%20160%201%201%20-3.8143395323225353%209.999999999613376e-11%20100%0AL%20496%20192%20512%20192%200%200%20true%205%200%0AL%20496%20272%20512%20272%200%200%20true%205%200%0Ag%20512%20288%20512%20304%200%0A368%20496%20192%20496%20160%200%200%0A368%20496%20272%20496%20240%200%200%0Ax%20536%20223%20589%20226%204%2012%20Click%5CsL%5Csto%5CsH%0A)  The switched voltage may not be identical but well within tolerance deviation for the LED Rs.  Although Rs is not found in datasheets, it occurs due to bulk resistance variations that affect Vf @ If variations.  Red is about 1.6V +If*10 Ohms @ 10mA and with a +50% tolerance worst case but +20% typ.

You may reduce the base resistors to lower the Rce effective value e.g. 220 Ohms.
[image]

Comment: Thank you. I don't need the led in my circuit. I'm still not sure how I should disable the connection to the original circuit while activating these NPNs. Would that still just be a relay?

Comment: The transistor as a polarized switch acts like a relay but with some small resistance. So it works like OR logic. either can be active in parallel. I don't know how you compute your R values

Comment: Sure, I get that that works for this part of the circuit. It was still going to be hooked to the wall console though, and that has another couple of resistors in it. I guess I could try to tune this resistors so that the overall resistance is the value I want... but not sure that's a good idea.